# Is there a way to print out certain elements of the JSON file in python?

Tags: python, json, api, key

I am using a (dutch) weather API and the result is showing a lot of information. However, I only want to print the temperature and location. Is there a way to filter out these keys?

```
from pip._vendor import requests
    

import json

response = requests.get(" http://weerlive.nl/api/json-data-10min.php?key=demo&locatie=52.0910879,5.1124231")


def jprint(obj):
    weer = json.dumps(obj, indent=2)
    print(weer)

jprint(response.json())
```

result:

```
{
  "liveweer": [
    {
      "place": "Utrecht",
      "temp": "7.7",
      "gtemp": "5.2",
      "summa": "Dry after rain",
      "lv": "89",
       etc.
```

How do I only print out the place and temp?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect the API to returns you a list of place, you can do:

```py
>>> {'liveweer': [{'plaats': item['plaats'], 'temp': item['temp']}] for item in response.json()['liveweer']}
{'liveweer': [{'plaats': 'Utrecht', 'temp': '8.0'}]}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. But this also works great and will be useful  in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
response = requests.get(" http://weerlive.nl/api/json-data-10min.php?key=demo&locatie=52.0910879,5.1124231")
data = response.json()
for station in data["liveweer"]:
    print(f"Temp in {station['plaats']} is {station['temp']}")
```

output

```
Temp in Utrecht is 8.0
```

Note that you can use convenient `Response.json()` method

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x=response.json()

print(x['liveweer'][0]['place'])
print(x['liveweer'][0]['temp'])
```

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly. Could you explain the '[0]' please?

Comment: [0] refers to the first element of the x['liveweer'] list (which is a dictionary). Bear in mind that my code will work for this specific structure that you provided. If the structure changes, it could not work. However you can adjust the code on the same logic

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in working with place and temp I would advise making a new dictionary.

```
import requests

r = requests.get(" http://weerlive.nl/api/json-data-10min.php?key=demo&locatie=52.0910879,5.1124231")

if r.status_code == 200:
    data = {
        "place" : r.json()['liveweer'][0]["place"], 
        "temp":  r.json()['liveweer'][0]["temp"],
    }
    print(data)
```